# swap problem in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: swap

Having problem with swap. Actually, in the system monitor it shows swap is not available, and then I installed GParted partition editor.

There is a partition named `/dev/sda7` and file system is `linux-swap`. I turned on swap from there and now everything becomes correct but when I reboot it is unable to persist the change. Again it is showing no swap in the system monitor.

Comment: Take a look at this page. It may help. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_more_swap.3F

Comment: Do you use encrypted swap? Then [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/430281/181442) might help

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the installation didn't added the swap partition to the fstab. This is easy to solve:

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo blkid`:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   /dev/sda1: UUID="bf554a2f-a035-4c22-bca8-162def35a03c" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda2: UUID="3962db06-3776-4f38-8ab9-eab6feeccc1d" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sdb1: UUID="AA64B45A64B42AC9" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sdb2: UUID="F66E431C6E42D551" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sdb3: UUID="75a0854b-8b6b-453f-8aec-2a081a1f19e3" TYPE="swap"
   ```

   I've marked the swap partition. Save the UUID value.
2. Edit the `/etc/fstab` file with whatever editor you like, but for efficiency sake I would tell you two methods:

   - Open the file with an editor using `sudo gedit` or `sudo vim` or `sudo nano`, whichever you like/feel better, then type this lines at the end (**be aware the I will be typing my owns since this is an example, you must change the UUID value**)

     ```
     UUID=75a0854b-8b6b-453f-8aec-2a081a1f19e3 none            swap    sw              0       0
     ```
   - Using a one liner. Type the following in a terminal:

     ```
     UUID="75a0854b-8b6b-453f-8aec-2a081a1f19e3"
     sudo sh -c "echo $UUID 'none swap sw 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
     ```
3. Now reboot your system, then type `free`:

   ```
                total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
   Mem:       1533744    1455700      78044          0      89548     690756
   -/+ buffers/cache:     675396     858348
   Swap:      1546232          0    1546232
   ```

   As you can see, the total swap is not 0. Same should happen with the system monitor